# A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$ is never injective?

Tags: real-analysis

Why is this the case? If we consider, for example, that on some open set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ we have $D_1f(x,y) \neq 0$, then for $g:A\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $g(x,y) = (f(x,y),y)$, we can easily verify that $g'\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and hence we can apply the Inverse Function Theorem. This is a hint given in Spivak, but I cannot see where to go from here.

Comment: It seems to me that Spivak is essentially re-demonstrating the Implicit Function Theorem. I mean, he suggests to use the same trick one uses to prove that theorem starting from the Inverse Function Theorem. I would rather use the Implicit Function Theorem and show that level sets of $f$ typically are curves, hence, there is at least one of them that is not reduced to a single point and $f$ is not injective. (Unless $f$ is constant, of course. In that case, forget about injectivity)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are simpler approaches to the problem besides the implicit function theorem. If $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ were continuous and injective, you could look at how $f$ behaves on a circle $C$.

For instance $f(\cos t, \sin t)$ would be continuous and monotone as a function of $t$. That leads to some problems as you complete a full trip around the circle.

Comment: (and this proof even works if $f$ is just $C^0$!)